# "PHP Suspected" Error/Hack...How do I do a fresh reset without losing anything?

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I discovered the WSOD after logging in to the backend of Wordpress and no matter what I did I couldn't fix it. It seems as though the problem is because of the php.suspected files I found and it seems like the cleanest way of getting rid of it is doing a clean wipe. 
How do I keep pages, plugins, theme, etc. so that when I wipe the site, I can get everything back? Whats the quickest but most efficient way of doing this?
Unfortunately I stopped doing backups so I don't have that. I'm using cPanel and Wordpress. If there's any additional info needed let me know.

Using WP DEBUG, it returned the following:
`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Requests_Cookie_Jar' not found in /home/d2ror3pa5bjl/public_html/wp-includes/class-requests.php:589 Stack trace: #0 /home/d2ror3pa5bjl/public_html/wp-includes/class-requests.php(363): Requests::set_defaults('http://updates....', Array, Array, 'POST', Array) #1 /home/d2ror3pa5bjl/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php(370): Requests::request('http://updates....', Array, Array, 'POST', Array) #2 /home/d2ror3pa5bjl/public_html/wp-includes/class-http.php(589): WP_Http->request('http://updates....', Array) #3 /home/d2ror3pa5bjl/public_html/wp-includes/http.php(187): WP_Http->post('http://updates....', Array) #4 /home/d2ror3pa5bjl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/essential-grid/admin/includes/update.class.php(169): wp_remote_post('http://updates....', Array) #5 /home/d2ror3pa5bjl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/essential-grid/admin/includes/update.class.php(29): Essential_Grid_Update->_retrieve_version_info() #6 /home/d2ror3pa5bjl/public_html/wp-content/plugins/essential-grid/admin/essential-gri in /home/d2ror3pa5bjl/public_html/wp-includes/class-requests.php on line 589`

Comment: What do the server error logs have? ... might be something very simple.

Comment: Not getting anything back from Metric Errors within cPanel

Comment: I added what WP Debug returned

Comment: "No matter what I did" - what does that mean? What have you tried to spot **any** information about what is going wrong? What have you tried to solve the given fatal error?

Comment: I've tried to solve it the best ways I could. I'm not familiar on how to solve for the first half of the FATAL ERROR, but I saw where Essential Grid was having an issue too and went and removed it from the plugins folder.

Answer (score 0):

For me "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Requests_Cookie_Jar' not found in ..." type error is usually when there is mistake in class name (like 'Request_Cookie_Jar' instead) or in path to it or in path where it is included or in namespace path or with not updated composer for autoloader (once i had big problem with this one).